# How can I send a notification (like in notification bell) to another user when form button is clicked in angular with ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, ajax, spring-boot, notifications

Is there a way to send a notification to another user when form button is clicked (when a new line is added to the database) in angular with ajax and javascript. I'm using springboot in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use push notifications or WebSocket to notify another user. Some of the related articles are below:

https://www.section.io/engineering-education/fcm-with-spring-and-angular/

https://www.stackextend.com/angular/websocket-with-spring-boot-and-angular/

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-websockets-sendtouser